# Bootstrap v4: understanding and adding custom classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

#### Motivation

[Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) (v4) currently does not have input tagging functionality. While libraries exist which provide tagging functionality (e.g. [TagsInput](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/), and [Select2](https://select2.org/) - specifically for select elements), neither provide the *exact* functionality that I want; namely, having [typeahead](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) supported tags in a `textarea` that are stacked vertically. While one can modify `Bloodhound` and these libraries to do so, given some other features I would like to personally add, I figure going from the ground up would be easier. In addition, as a new [Bootstrap] user I am quite fond of their light but functional javascript and wanted to take a moment to try and learn from them. In addition, while I have written a lot of javascript, I am not a jQuery user, so this would provide a jumping point into jQuery as well.

While making a functional tagging library is outside the scope of any single S.O. question, making a new bootstrap class (heavily incumbent upon an existing class) should be in scope.

#### Context

If we think about what a "tag" is - in context of input - it is simply the user provided input encased in some form of block/bubble often with a dismiss-able button nearby.  [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) (v4) has a class which already has most of the stylistic features implemented - [alerts](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/js/src/alert.js). The provided link is to the source code. In essence, to build upon the [Alert](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/js/src/alert.js) class, I can either inherit or just copy-paste and replace all instances of "alert" with "tag". The result of doing so can be found at the bottom of the post for readability.

As being a beginner to jQuery, there is a lot I do not understand about their code. Even having written a fair amount of javascript, I have also never had the use for export and import statements - which were causing errors when trying to use the code.

So I went ahead and from the [Util](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/js/src/util.js) source code, copy-pasted the three needed features from [`util.js`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/js/src/util.js):

```
Util.TRANSITION_END, 
Util.getTransitionDurationFromElement(element), 
Util.getSelectorFromElement(element)
```

I figured that I would now be good to go, assuming jQuery is already loaded.
It turns out that this is not the case. I have the error:

```
TypeError: element.getAttribute is not a function
tag.js:67:24
```

where line 67 is the first line of the pasted-over `Util.getSelectorFromElement(element)` function:

```
let selector = element.getAttribute('data-target')
```

#### Question(s)

So, in short, my question is, how can I incorporate my "new" class (copy pasting the alert class into a new file and renaming it be the tag class) into my local version of [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)?

Any additional insights into the class structure used by [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) would also be appreciated.

```
const Tag = (($) => {
  /**
   * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   * Constants
   * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   */
  const NAME = 'tag'
  const VERSION = '0'
  const DATA_KEY = `bs.tag`
  const EVENT_KEY = `.${DATA_KEY}`
  const DATA_API_KEY = '.data-api'
  const JQUERY_NO_CONFLICT = $.fn[NAME]

  const Selector = {
    DISMISS : '[data-dismiss="tag"]'
  }

  const Event = {
    CLOSE : `close${EVENT_KEY}`,
    CLOSED : `closed${EVENT_KEY}`,
    CLICK_DATA_API: `click${EVENT_KEY}${DATA_API_KEY}`
  }

  const ClassName = {
    TAG: 'tag',
    FADE: 'fade',
    SHOW: 'show'
  }

  /**
   * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   * Class Definition
   * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   */
  class Tag {
    constructor(element) {
      this._element = element
    }

    // Getters
    static get VERSION() {
      return VERSION
    }

    // Public
    close(element) {
      element = element || this._element
      const rootElement = this._getRootElement(element)
      const customEvent = this._triggerCloseEvent(rootElement)

      if (customEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        return
      }

      this._removeElement(rootElement)
    }

    dispose() {
      $.removeData(this.element, DATA_KEY)
      this._element = null
    }

    // Private
    _getRootElement(element) {

      const selector = function(element) {
        let selector = element.getAttribute('data-target')
        if (!selector || selector === '#') {
          selector = element.getAttribute('href') || ''
        }
        try {
          const $selector = $(document).find(selector)
          return $selector.length > 0 ? selector : null
        } catch (err) {
          return null
        }
      }
      // const selector = Util.getSelectorFromElement(element)
      let parent     = false

      if (selector) {
        parent = $(selector)[0]
      }

      if (!parent) {
        parent = $(element).closest(`.${ClassName.TAG}`)[0]
      }
      return parent
    }



    _triggerCloseEvent(element) {
      const closeEvent = $.Event(Event.CLOSE)

      $(element).trigger(closeEvent)
      return closeEvent
    }

    _removeElement(element) {
      $(element).removeClass(ClassName.SHOW)

      if (!$(element).hasClass(ClassName.FADE)) {
        this._destroyElement(element)
        return
      }

      const transitionDuration = function(element) {
        if (!element) {
          return 0
        }

        // Get transition-duration of the element
        let transitionDuration = $(element).css('transition-duration')
        const floatTransitionDuration = parseFloat(transitionDuration)

        // Return 0 if element or transition duration is not found
        if (!floatTransitionDuration) {
          return 0
        }

        // If multiple durations are defined, take the first
        transitionDuration = transitionDuration.split(',')[0]

        return parseFloat(transitionDuration) * MILLISECONDS_MULTIPLIER
      }
      // const transitionDuration = Util.getTransitionDurationFromElement(element)

      $(element)
        .one('transitionend', (event) => this._destroyElement(element, event))
        .emulateTransitionEnd(transitionDuration)
        // .one(Util.TRANSITION_END, (event) => this._destroyElement(element, event))
    }

    _destroyElement(element) {
      $(element)
        .detach()
        .trigger(Event.CLOSED)
        .remove()
    }

    // Static
    static _jQueryInterface(config) {
      return this.each(function () {
        const $element = $(this)
        let data       = $element.data(DATA_KEY)

        if (!data) {
          data = new Alert(this)
          $element.data(DATA_KEY, data)
        }

        if (config === 'close') {
          data[config](this)
        }
      })
    }


    static _handleDismiss(tagInstance) {
      return function (event) {
        if (event) {
          event.preventDefault()
        }

        tagInstance.close(this)
      }
    }
  }


  /**
   * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   * Data Api implementation
   * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   */

  $(document).on(
    Event.CLICK_DATA_API,
    Selector.DISMISS,
    Tag._handleDismiss(new Tag())
  )

  /**
   * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   * jQuery
   * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   */

  $.fn[NAME]             = Tag._jQueryInterface
  $.fn[NAME].Constructor = Tag
  $.fn[NAME].noConflict  = function () {
    $.fn[NAME] = JQUERY_NO_CONFLICT
    return Tag._jQueryInterface
  }

  return Tag
})($)
// export default Tag
```

Comment: I wouldn't rename bootstrap alert class... if you do that, you will face problem every time you update your bootstrap, because your new class tag will disappear. If it was me, I would copy the functionality that I want from bootstrap, put it in a new file, rename the class and add the new file to my project... on top of bootstrap.

Comment: @Sarhang I apologize if I was not clear. That is what I meant. I said "rename" as - in essence - it is copy-paste to new file, find-replace alert with tag.

Comment: Wouldn't the [badge with close icon](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/badge/) be closer to a "tag"?

Comment: @ZimSystem could be. The styles are very similar. The point is to take alert (or as you suggest badge) and use it as a starting point to build the multi-line tags describe above. I was not sure if badges already had the close build in. Alerts do.

Comment: @ZimSystem, just doubled check, badge is pure css. Alert has the JS class for close. I am not saying one can not re-implement for badge (see my MWE here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49465445/bootstrap-v4-responsive-multiple-typeahead-textarea-tagging ) but to make a dedicated tag class, building off alert seems to be the right direction